# How to extend JQuery Event with prototype

Tags: jquery, prototype, jquery-events

I am trying to create a class that will extend the jQuery `.trigger()` and `.on()` functionality.

This code does not work:

```
var myclass = new $();
myclass.set =   function (key, value){
    this[key] = value;
    this.trigger('change', {key: key, value: value});
}

myclass.on('change', function (e, param) {
  console.log("Hello there");
});
myclass.set('student', 23);
```

I also have tried it like this:

```
var MyClass = function () {
  this.set = function () {
     this[key] = value;
     this.trigger('change', {key: key, value: value});
  }
}

MyClass.prototype = new $();
var myclass = new MyClass();

myclass.on('change', function (e, param) {
  console.log("Hello there");
});
myclass.set('student', 23);
```

but this code works:

```
var myclass ={
  set:  function (key, value){
    this[key] = value;
    $(this).trigger('change', {key: key, value: value});
  }
}

$(myclass).on('change', function (e, param) {
  console.log("Hello there");
});
myclass.set('student', 23);
```

In the previous code I am trying to append a 'set' function to the new object to `$()` function .

Comment: U should clone $.Event first then modify its prototype

Comment: @EricSo,  I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this right ?

```
var MySubClass = function(){};
MySubClass.prototype = new $.Event()
```